# Bootstrap 4 hide one column on mobile device

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this code:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="ava-block">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                   ....
                </div>
</div>
```

How I can hide first `col-lg-3` on mobile and update `col-lg-6` to `col-lg-9`?
I don't need show `col-lg-3` on mobile devices. But if I hide on css with `media` then `col-lg-6` is not resize to full width.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Is this inside a container? Which col-lg-3, one or both? If you hide both then col-lg-6 would be resized to 12, not 9.

Comment: @Zim Only first `col-lg-3`

Comment: use `d-none` for hide in all devices and `d-md-block` for show your code above 992px, for more information visit https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want something like this. Use the [display utils](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/display/) to show/hide the column. Use `col` for the `col-lg-6` so that it always fills the remaining width.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 d-none d-lg-block">
            <div class="ava-block border">
                3
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="ava-block border">
                6-9
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="ava-block border">
                3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/gyuRoUt68s

Answer (score -3):

To hide a div on mobile you have to use the css class `.d-none .d-sm-block` and to make a div only big on mobile you have to use `.col-xs-9`

So:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="d-none d-sm-block col-lg-3">
    <div class="ava-block">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-9 col-lg-6">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    ....
  </div>
</div>
```

Check [Bootstrap's documentation on display](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/)